# Can someone help to download protected pdf?

Tags: windows-10, pdf

I am trying to download a PDF file from a site that lets me only view it.  I visited the site a few months back, and back then I could easily download PDFs.  Recently however, they seem to have undergone a layout change of their website.

I have tried this, and put ".pdf" after the link, but it said webpage not found.

Can anybody tell me how to download the PDF?
http://krishikosh.egranth.ac.in/handle/1/5810016000

Comment: If you can view it, it has already been downloaded. Firefox even has a "Save as" button in its PDF viewer.

Answer (score 5):

#### Can anybody tell me how to download the PDF?

Scroll to the bottom of the page and click the View/Open button to view the file:

[image].

You can look at the document properties when viewing the file, which give the filename:

[image]

Then a google search for:

```
"PAU-Simranjit Kaur.pdf" site:http://krishikosh.egranth.ac.in
```

Gives us the file URL:

```
http://krishikosh.egranth.ac.in/bitstream/1/5810016000/1/PAU-Simranjit%20Kaur.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

Press `Ctrl+Shift+I` and open Dev tools in Google Chrome and look at the Network tab and see which requests are being made.

You'll find the URL address of the PDF:

`http://krishikosh.egranth.ac.in/bitstream/1/5810016000/1/PAU-Simranjit%20Kaur.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

Download & Install Git from https://git-scm.com/

On the View page for the pdf press F12 to open the inspector. search "iframe" until you find iframe Value with bitstream. Copy the value

Replace that with xxx in the following code:

curl 'https://krishikosh.egranth.ac.in/xxx' -H 'keyname: Akz914723960' -H 'Type: application/pdf' -d '' -o C:/name.pdf

Replace "name" with the file name you want to give the pdf ... it will download to your C drive folder.